No sound on Jumper EZBook s7 on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
This laptop (a Jumper S7 Hi) played sound in the Windows installer. I don't know if it plays sound in Windows because I did not wish to install Windows. In Ubuntu it does not normally play any sound. After a reboot while I had headphones plugged in to the 3.5mm port, it played sound successfully from the built-in speakers (not the headphones) for a while, before stopping, perhaps after the laptop was suspended. Rebooting without the headphones plugged in does not produce sound.
Going through the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting checklist:
$ pacmd
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.

Is this a problem? ps aux | grep pulse tells me that pipewire-pulse is running. Does that or some other software do the job of the PulseAudio daemon or do I need to find a way to get the PulseAudio daemon running?
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav and sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav from the Alt+F2 prompt do not make any sound. The same commands from a terminal also do not make any sound.
$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofessx8336 [sof-essx8336], device 0: ES8336 (*) []
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofessx8336 [sof-essx8336], device 5: HDMI 1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofessx8336 [sof-essx8336], device 6: HDMI 2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofessx8336 [sof-essx8336], device 7: HDMI 3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

find /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep snd gives me a long list of modules. Seems ok.
$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Device 1c6c:122a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 133, IOMMU group 12
    Memory at b1118000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl

Seems ok.
Is my soundcard supported on the list at https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Main ? I don't know if it is or isn't. How do I find the name of my soundcard in a format I can look up on that list? I can't find it on the list but I do have a kernel module for it, so shouldn't that mean it's supported?
lsmod tells me
snd                   143360  21 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi

Actually that's weird because previously lsmod told me
snd                   143360  25 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_sof_es8336,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi

The difference is that the first time I tried lsmod it had snd_soc_sof_es8336 on that list, and the second time not, although I don't think I changed anything. Also the second time it had snd_hda_codec_realtek which was not present the first time. Strange, don't know what would be changing those modules.
alsamixer says "Card: PipeWire, Chip: PipeWire, Item:Master," with only a single volume slider, and the volume is set to 46 right now, not muted. If I press F6 to change the sound card, I can change it from "- (default)" to "default:0 HDA Intel PCH." If I do that, the alsamixer display changes to say "Card: HDA Intel PCH, Chip: RealTek ALC3234, Item: Master." There are two screens full of volume controls here, and I've increased the volumes that I can increase, though I'm not sure what they all mean.


Maybe there is a hardware problem? I did get some static once and some squealing another time, though mostly it has been silent.
The squealing can be triggered by switching to a virtual terminal (ctrl alt f3) and back (ctrl alt f2).

Since you see that PipeWire is running, you could try restarting it to see if that helps. Sometimes, simply restarting the audio service can fix odd issues. You can do that with:
systemctl --user restart pipewire


Tried this - didn't work. On a different topic, I did find out how to trigger the weird squealing noise again. If I switch to a virtual terminal (ctrl-alt-f3) and back (ctrl-alt-f2) the speaker starts squealing.

Well, I solved this problem by getting an external USB audio card for $3. Now sound plays on headphones plugged into the USB card, which is all that matters to me.
